# Ejecutar un método primero y luego lo demás

Tags: java, android

¿Cómo puedo ejecutar primero **cerrar teclado** y luego lo demás?

```
    menuCategorias.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //cerrar teclado
            mEmptyBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mSearchSrcTextView.setText("");
            mSearchSrcTextView.setCursorVisible(false);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            //
            if(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED == bsb.getState()){
                //cerrar
                menuCategorias.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_categorias);
                bsb.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }else{
                //abrir
                menuCategorias.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_categorias_close);
                bsb.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: puede pasar que el tiempo de la animacion de cerrar teclado sea mas rapido que el fire de lo demas, te recomiendo anidar la funcion. y antes de la siguiente colocarle un delay de 1 segundo.

Comment: Lo pensé, pero es esa realmente la mejor manera de realizarlo? Funcionaría en todos los móviles? Es decir, cada móvil, tendrá un tiempo de reacción en las acciones, no? Gracias ! @FranciscoNúñéz

Comment: aunque no lo tenga y aunque esto pueda cambiarse creo que 1 segundo estaría perfecto... ya que no se notaria por muy poco tiempo el solapamiento de efectos.

Comment: es mas encontre algo interesante que tal vez te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596309/how-to-detect-keyboard-animation-end-in-android-or-instantly-hide-keyboard-with

Comment: si te sirve me dices para agregarlo como respuesta saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea es sobrescribir el método `dispatchTouchEvent` para detectar cualquier click en la pantalla, usar `Rect` para crear un punto con la localización del `EditText` y por ultimo comprobar si el click fue fuera de dicho `EditText`:

```
private Rect mRect = new Rect();
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

    int[] localizacion = new int[2];
    mSearchSrcTextView.getLocationOnScreen(localizacion);
    mRect.left = localizacion[0];
    mRect.top = localizacion[1];
    mRect.right = localizacion[0] + mSearchSrcTextView.getWidth();
    mRect.bottom = localizacion[1] + mSearchSrcTextView.getHeight();

    int x = (int) ev.getX();
    int y = (int) ev.getY();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !mRect.contains(x, y)) {
        InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mSearchSrcTextView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Con esto, se solventa al pulsar en cualquier parte de la pantalla, tanto si el ítem pulsado no requiere foco, como podría ser un `TextView`.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias !! @Israel